# Avoid While loop repeating message when keeping apache alive

Tags: bash, apache, shell

I am trying to keep apache alive while the background process is running in a CGI shell script using this:

```
if [[ `ps -p $pid | wc -l` -gt 1 ]]
then
    output="Program is running. Running time depends on the number of alternatively spliced proteins the submitted gene has. Results will be displayed here."
   # echo -n "The program is running...\n"
    echo "<html>"
    echo "<head>"
    echo "</head>"
    echo "<body>"
    echo "<table width="750" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">"
    echo "<tr><td><img src=\"../../images/calc.gif\" align=\"absmiddle\"> <strong> $output </strong></td></tr>"
    echo "</table>"
    echo "</body>"
    echo "</html>"
fi
```

Where "$pid" contains the process ID. And, the "calc.gif" is a gif which plays while the process is running at the background. The "timeout" in my "httpd.conf" file is set to 1200 seconds. Sometimes the scripts takes longer. I thought by using the approach above I will keep the apache alive since the "calc.gif" is playing, but it does not work.

I know I could use a while loop like this:

```
while kill -0 $pid
do
    output="Program is running. Running time depends on the number of alternatively spliced proteins the submitted gene has. Results will be displayed here."
   # echo -n "The program is running...\n"
    echo "<html>"
    echo "<head>"
    echo "</head>"
    echo "<body>"
    echo "<table width="750" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">"
    echo "<tr><td><img src=\"../../images/calc.gif\" align=\"absmiddle\"> <strong> $output </strong></td></tr>"
    echo "</table>"
    echo "</body>"
    echo "</html>"
done
```

But, the drawback of this solution is, it keeps printing the "$output" line on the page multiple times. Can someone please help me know how can I avoid this multiple printing on the webpage? Or an alternate solution to keep the apache alive even after the program exceeds "timeout=1200".

Comment: Stop trying to keep apache alive. Spawn a background process that runs independently on apache, then redirect to a page that lets the browser use meta-refresh or ajax to poll it until it's done.

Comment: Thanks! Am new to ajax/meta-refresh. Could you please help me understand it with an example. I would really appreciate it :-) thank you.

Comment: if you put `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">` in the page you send back, the browser will auto-refresh after 10 seconds. That means that if a background process will eventually create a file `/tmp/myfile`, your script can do `if [ -e /tmp/myfile ]; then cat /tmp/myfile; else echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">'; echo 'The file is unavailable, please wait'; fi` and then exit. The page will be requested again, so you don't need to keep apache alive. (Make sure not to start a new background process every 10 seconds though)